# Can I link and instantiate a ViewModel in XAML or do I need to do this in backing .cs?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Frame 
      xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"   
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
      x:Class="Japanese.PhrasesFrame">
      <StackLayout x:Name="phrasesFrameStackLayout">
```

and backing .cs

```cs
public partial class PhrasesFrame : Frame
{
    public PhrasesFrameViewModel vm = new PhrasesFrameViewModel();

    public PhrasesFrame(PhrasesPage phrasesPage)
    {
        phrasesFrameStackLayout.BindingContext = vm;
```

and ViewModel

```cs
public class PhrasesFrameViewModel : ObservableProperty
{
```

Can someone tell me is it necessary for me to create a new instance of PhrasesFrameViewModel() in the backing .cs or is there a more efficient way of doing the creating of this and the binding of this in the XAML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set value `inside a model` ,then you don't need to create a new instance in backing.cs.

In Model:

```cs
public class PhrasesFrameViewModel
{
    public string Parameter1 { set; get; } = "P1";
    public bool Parameter2 { set; get; } = true;
    public List<string> Parameter3 { set; get; } = new List<string>(){"1","2"};
}
```

In XMAL:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Frame xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectName" 
x:Class="ProjectName.PhrasesFrame"
>


<StackLayout x:Name="phrasesFrameStackLayout">
    <StackLayout.BindingContext>
        <local:PhrasesFrameViewModel/>
    </StackLayout.BindingContext>

    <Label Text = "{Binding Parameter1}"/>
    <Switch IsToggled = "{Binding Parameter2}"/>

    <ListView ItemsSource = "{Binding Parameter3}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <TextCell Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

Result:

[image]